# Alembic not generating correct changes

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I am using `Flask-Migrate==2.0.0`. Its not detecting the changes correctly. Every time I run `python manage db migrate` it generates a script for all models although they have been added successfully in previous revisions. I have added two new columns to a table, migration revision is supposed to have only those two new columns instead all tables are added to it. Is there anything I am missing?

**EDIT 1**

Here is whats happening.
I added Flask_Migrate to my project.

```
python manage db init
python manage db migrate
python manage db upgrade
```

Flask-Migrate generated tables for models plus alembic_version table with having revision

> 985efbf37786

After this I made some changes. I added two new columns in one of my table and run the command again

```
python manage db migrate
```

It generated new revision

> 934ba2ddbd44

but instead of adding just only those two new columns, the revision contains script for all tables plus those two new columns. So for instance in my first revision, I have something like this

```
op.create_table('forex_costs',
sa.Column('code', sa.String(), nullable=False),
sa.Column('country', sa.String(), nullable=False),
sa.Column('rate', sa.Numeric(), nullable=False),
sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('code', 'country', name='forex_costs_id'),
schema='regis'
)
```

The second revision also contains exactly the same code. I don't understand why if its already generated.

I googled it a little and my problems looks exactly like this https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/93 but I am not using oracle DB. I am using Postgresql. Also I don't know if it has any effect but I am not creating my tables in Default Public Schema, instead I am creating two new schemas (schema_a and schema_b) as I have a lot of tables(Around 100). So just to arrange them.

**EDIT 2**

The first problem seems to have resolved by adding

> include_schemas=True

in env.py.

Now the new migration is not trying to create already existing tables again but it has some issues with **foreign keys**. Every time I create a new revision, it tries to remove the already existing foreign keys and then tries to add them. Logs looks like this

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (post_id)(post_id) on table album_photos
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (album_id)(album_id) on table album_photos
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (user_id)(user_id) on table album_photos
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (album_id)(album_id) on table prodcat.album_photos
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (post_id)(post_id) on table prodcat.album_photos
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (user_id)(user_id) on table prodcat.album_photos
```

I have tried adding name to each Foreign Key constraint but that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Have you seen this discussion regarding your problem? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-alembic/FA8wpmPJc7U

Comment: @Waseem: did you get a full proof answer to this?

Comment: @Shashank Yes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193382/818731) is full proof answer by Michael Bayer, Author of Alembic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting search_path to public fixed this issue. I always thought that in addition to setting schema info explicitly on each model, we also need to add those schemas on search_path. I was wrong. Changing postgresql search_path is not necessary once schemas are defined explicitly on each model.

> The search path means that reflected foreign key definitions will not
>   match what you have in your model. This only applies to foreign keys
>   because that's how Postgresql does it. Read through
>   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#remote-schema-table-introspection-and-postgresql-search-path
>   for background. - Michael Bayer

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for coming back and providing your feedback after you solved the issue. I had grief with the same issue for 2 hours while using `postgres`

Btw, I would like to point out that you would have to include the `include_schemas` option in the block `context.configure`, like so:

```
context.configure(connection=connection,
                  target_metadata=target_metadata,
                  include_schemas=True,
                  process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
                  **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)
```